# cannot convert 'int (B::*)(std::string)' to 'int (*)(std::string) ' in assignment pt2function=&B::generate_callback;

Tags: c++, class, oop, callback, function-pointers

I am new to c++, .I am trying to create a pgm that contains 2 classes ,out of which one class has a member function that would generate a callback function in another class though a function pointer, but i keep getting the following error.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;



    class B
    {
    private:    std::string str1;
    public:    int generate_callback(std::string str1);


    };
    int  B::generate_callback(std::string str1)
    {
        if ((str1=="Generate")||(str1=="generate"))
        {
            Cout<<"Callback generated ";
        }
    return 0;
    }

    class A : public B
    {
    public:
                void count(int a,int b);
        private: int a,b;

    };


    void A::count(int a, int b)
    {
        for ( a=1;a<b;a++){
            if(a==50)
            {
                cout<<"Generating callback ";

                goto exit;

        }
    exit: ;
    }
    }

    int (*pt2function)(string)=NULL;
    int main()
    {
       B obj1;
       A obj2;
       string str;
       cout<<"To generate callback at int i=50 please enter 'generate'";
       cin>>str;
       obj2.count(1,100);
       pt2function=&B::generate_callback;
       (obj1.*pt2function)(str);
        return 0;
    }
```

The errors :

```
main.cpp:57: error: cannot convert 'int (B::*)(std::string) {aka int (B::*)(std::basic_string<char>)}' to 'int (*)(std::string) {aka int (*)(std::basic_string<char>)}' in assignment
    pt2function=&B::generate_callback;

/home/adt/practice/N_practise/n_pract_2/pract2/main.cpp:58: error: 'pt2function' cannot be used as a member pointer, since it is of type 'int (*)(std::string) {aka int (*)(std::basic_string<char>)}'
    (obj1.*pt2function)(str);
           ^
           ^
```

Comment: A pointer to a member function is not the same as a pointer to a non-member function, and `pt2function` is a pointer to a non-member function. I suggest you look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what corrections do i go ahead with if i have to use function pointers?

Comment: You need to make `pt2function` a pointer to a `B` member function. The syntax is basically shown in the error message.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is correct right? i have declared pt2function as a function pointer tht points to a function that takes in a string but returns an int. that function being generate_callback in B class. I know its too much, but could you share that corrected line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `pt2function` is a pointer to a ***non-member*** function. Such a pointer is not compatible with a pointer to a member-function. Which is what the compiler tells you with the first error: A `int (*)(string)` is not compatible with a `int (B::*)(string)`.

You need to define `pt2function` as a pointer to a `B` member function:

```
int (B::*pt2function)(string)=NULL;
```

Now you can initialize or assign a matching member function of `B` to the variable `pt2function`.

This also solves the second errors, which basically says that in your current code the variable `pt2function` is not a pointer to a member function, and therefore can not be used as such.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to functions and pointers to member functions are really different beasts.

You have mainly two options to get it working in your code:

- Change this line:

  ```
  int (*pt2function)(string)=NULL;
  ```

  To this:

  ```
  int (B::*pt2function)(string)=NULL;
  ```

  That is defining `pt2function` as a pointer to a member function of `B` that gets a `string` and returns an `int`.
- Declare the `generate_callback` as a static method and invoke it as `pt2function(str);` in your `main` function.
  In fact, a static member function can be assigned to a pointer to function like the one you have already in use.